# Java JSON printing

Tags: java, json

JSON code (test2) for reference

```
{
    "forecast": {
        "txt_forecast": {
            "date": "8: 00AMMST",
            "forecastday": [
                {
                    "period": 0,
                    "icon": "partlycloudy",
                    "icon_url": "http: //icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
                    "title": "Thursday",
                    "fcttext": "Partlycloudy.Highof63F.Windslessthan5mph.",
                    "fcttext_metric": "Partlycloudy.Highof17C.Windslessthan5km/h.",
                    "pop": "0"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Java code for reference

```
     Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\test2.json"));

     JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
     String name = (String) jsonObject.get("forecast").toString();
     System.out.println(name);
```

When I use this java code It prints out the entirety of "forecast" (IE, it prints out the date, period, icon, title, ect...). My question is, how do I print out specific parts of the JSON code without printing out ALL of the code. I'm using JSON-SIMPLE, thanks.

Comment: What does `jsonObject.get("forecast")` return without the `.toString()` seems to me it would be another `JSONObject` that you could drill into.

Comment: @Shaded it basically returns every variable in the JSON file.

Comment: You've already asked this question. What was wrong with the answers you received?

Comment: @iamnotmaynard the answers were not clear enough

Comment: If the answers are not clear, ask for clarification on the original question, don't waste peoples effort by opening a new question that asks the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\test2.json"));

JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
JSONObject forecast = jsonObject.get("forecast");
JSONObject txt__forecast = jsonObject.get("txt_forecast");
JSONArray forecastday = jsonObject.getJSONArray("forecastday");
JSONObject forecastIdx0 = forecastday.get(0);
int period = forecastIdx0.getInt("period");
Stting title = forecastIdx0.getString("title");
```

Normally you would not store them on every call. I just did this to show what each of the get calls return. As you can tell this is pretty verbose. If you are working with JSON in more than a simple way you benefit greatly in using an object deserialization library such as GSON that allows you to straight deserialize into a pre defined object.

For reference refer to http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html it is the official Json library that is used for low level manipulation and traversal of json. Its used everywhere and by every thing that interacts with json.